# How do I execute a *.cmd in another dir as if it is running in the current dir?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

Imagine the following cmd

```
c:\myscript.cmd

java.exe myclass.class
```

Where the file it is running is in:

```
c:\temp\myclass.class
```

I want to run a cmd file as if it is being run in the current directory, ie my command line is open in `c:\temp\`

I want a shorter way of running:

```
c:\temp\>mv ../myscript.cmd .
c:\temp\>myscript.cmd
c:\temp\>mv myscript.cmd ..\
```

My question is: **How do I execute a *.cmd in another dir as if it is running in the current dir?**

Comment: You could invoke a child-instance of `cmd` with its working-directory as the target.

Comment: Could you expand that into an answer?

Comment: You can run scripts by providing a full or relative path, e.g. `c:\myscript.cmd` or even `../myscript.cmd`.

Comment: Does the path shown in the prompt really have a trailing backslash?  That shouldn't happen, and may be related to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can spawn a child `cmd` instance that then executes `cd` to change the working directory followed by the command to execute, this is done by running `cmd` directly, along with `&&` to concatenate commands:

```
cmd /c "cd PATH_OF_DESIRED_WORKING_DIRECTORY" && "myscript.cmd"
```

Comment: Except that the question asks how to *not* change the current directory. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Setting the current directory is necessary, but this technique means that the `cd` command only affects `myscript.cmd` and not the "current" current directory in the parent cmd context.

Comment: Why would setting the current directory be necessary?  According to the question, the existing current directory `c:\temp` is already correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to run it, then just type `..\myscript.cmd` at the command line.  It gets your current directory as its current directory.  You can verify this by putting `echo %CD%` as the first line of the batch file. It should print `c:\temp\`